# Multiple insertion points in polymer module?

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, html5-template

In polymer, we can create insertion points for HTML content with `<content>` within custom modules like this.

```
<my-custom-element>
  Surrounding HTML ...
  <content></content>
  Surrounding HTML ...
</my-custom-element>
```

and then later use the module like this:

```
<my-custom-element>foo content</my-custom-element>
```

Can a custom element support multiple of these `<content>`-based insertion points? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *standard* selection of elements from `<template>` using the `<content>`'s `select` attribute with a CSS selector to get different inserted elements.

```
<template>
  Name : <content select="h2"></content><br>
  Mail : <content select="#mail"></content>
</tempalte>

<my-custom-element>
    <h2>Some One</h2>
    <span id="mail">email@internet.com</span>
</my-custom-element>
```

Comment: Beware: in Polymer 2.0, `<content>` is going to be changed to `<slot>`, the behavior stays the same. https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#shadow-dom-v1

Comment: @LeBird you're right <content> element is deprecated in the WhatWg/W3C specs too.